# Prove or disprove this integral of a function, defined on a countable set with infinite limit points, converges to zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits-and-convergence, partitions, sumsets

**Edit: I got rid of my old definitions. Everything should be clear now**

Since no one has answered [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637157/how-do-prove-the-darboux-like-sum-of-a-function-defined-on-a-countable-set-with) on MSE, I’m hoping to get an answer here. I apologize if you dislike my writing. I am an undergraduate student and I don’t know whether this is a research question.

---

### Definition

Consider a continuous $f:A\to[0,1]$ where $A\subseteq[0,1]$.

**Edit: I did not use [@Mathworker21's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3340521/125918) because I assumed it would not give the result I am looking for.** Now I realize this is not the case. Here is his definition.

> We can assume $A \subseteq [a,b]$, since that's where everything is happening. For ease, I'll have $[a,b] = [0,1]$. Based on the above discussion, I'll just have $P$ be defined on all of $[0,1]$ and continuous. Let $E_1 = [0,1], E_2 = [0,\frac{1}{2}], E_3 = [\frac{1}{2},1], E_4 = [0,\frac{1}{4}], E_5 = [\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}], E_6 = [\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]$, $E_7 = [\frac{3}{4},1], E_8 = [0,\frac{1}{8}]$, etc.
>
> If $A$ is finite, it's obvious how to define the average of $P$ (just do $\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{x \in A} P(x)$). So, assume $A$ is infinite. Consider the sets $A\cap E_1, A\cap E_2, \dots$. Let $x_1$ be a point in the first nonempty one of these sets. Let $x_2$ be a point in the second nonempty of these sets, etc. Look at the measures $\delta_{x_1}, \frac{\delta_{x_1}+\delta_{x_2}}{2}, \dots, \frac{\delta_{x_1}+\dots+\delta_{x_N}}{N},\dots$. Since $[0,1]$ is a compact metric space, there is some probability measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ that is a weak* limit of some subsequence of these measures, i.e. there is some $(N_k)_k$ with $\frac{1}{N_k}\sum_{j=1}^{N_k} f(x_j) \to \int_0^1 f d\mu$ for each $f \in C([0,1])$.
>
> We then define the average of $P$ over $A$ to be $\int_0^1 Pd\mu$.

---

> For concreteness, suppose that $$f=\operatorname{id}$$ and
>   $$A=\left\{\frac{1}{2^x}+\frac{1}{2^y}+\frac{1}{2^z}:x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}\right\}\cap[0,1]$$
>
> My guess is, in this case, the average will converge to $0$. How do we prove whether I am right or wrong? Could we create a better definition that is easier to compute or gives an exact value?

### Possible evidence that the average is zero

Here is a number line plot of all elements of set $A$

```
generateA[n_Integer] := 
 Select[Union@
   Flatten[Table[
     1/2^x + 1/2^y + 1/2^z, {x, 1, n}, {y, x, n}, {z, y, n}]], 
  0 <= # <= 1 &]
NumberLinePlot[generateA[50], PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.003]]
```

It appears the points become "denser" near $0$. If the 'densest point' carries the most weight in the average, it is possible that the average should be $f(0)=0$.

Also by analysis, if we take the function inside $A$ and set $x$ as constant $a$ and $y$ as constant $b$, taking $z\to\infty$ we get

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2^a}+\frac{1}{2^b}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}\right\}$$

This represents all the limit points. Since the limit points are "infinitely denser" than finite points, they should have infinitely greater weight for the average.

If we set $b\to\infty$ we get

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2^a}:a\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}\right\}$$

These represent second-order limit points "closely approximated" by first-order limit and finite points. The second-order limit points should have infinitely more weight than the lower order limit points.

As $a\to\infty$, we get $0$, the third order limit point and the densest point in the set. Third-order limit points should have infinitely more weight than second order, first order, and finite limit point.

From our analysis, it's possible, the average is $f(0)=0$.

Finally, consider the following code (from Wolfram Mathematica). This replicates $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$ which I mentioned earlier:

```
partition[a_List, s_] := Module[{f, r}, f[{}, x_] := {x};
  f[l_List, x_] := If[x - l[[1]] < s, Append[l, x], Sow[l]; {x}];
  r = Reap[Fold[f, {}, a]];
  Append[r[[2, 1]], r[[1]]]]
partition[{0, 1, 2, 7, 10, 11, 12}, 5]
(*{{0,1,2},{7,10,11},{12}}*)
calculate[p_, a_, s_] := 
 Module[{parts = partition[a, s], n, inf, sup}, n = Length[parts];
  inf = Total[Min[p /@ #] & /@ parts];
  sup = Total[Max[p /@ #] & /@ parts];
  {inf/n, sup/n}]
calculate[Identity, generateA[500], N[10^(-170)]] // N
```

I get:

```
{0.00598798, 0.00598798}
```

But it took a long time to compute. In fact, the [person who gave me this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220088/34171) doesn't think the sum converges to $0$ when $f=\operatorname{id}$? How do we prove otherwise?

### <s>Deleted Definition</s>

> Let $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{A \subseteq [0,1]}$, and let $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{P}$ be a partition of $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{[0,1]}$ such that it is a finite set of sub-intervals $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{X}$ with disjoint interiors and each subinterval has the same length. Define $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{P' = \{ X\in P: X\cap A \neq \emptyset\}}$. Define $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{n' = |P'|}$ (the cardinality of a finite set, or in this case, the number of sub-intervals whose intersection with $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{A}$ is non-empty).

Calculate/define the following:

$$\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{L_{f,P} = \frac{1}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}} \bigg(\inf_{t \in X}f(t) \bigg)}$$

$$\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{U_{f,P} = \frac{1}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}} \bigg(\sup_{t \in X}f(t) \bigg)}$$

Define the limits under refinements of $P$ like so:
$$\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{L_f = \lim_{\|P\| \to 0}(L_{f,P})}$$
$$\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{U_f = \lim_{\|P\| \to 0}(U_{f,P})}$$

Where $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\|P\|=\sup_{X\in P}\|X\|}$.

$\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{L_f}$ is the 'lower average' of $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f}$ on $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{[0,1]}$ (with respect to partition $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{P}$). Likewise, $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{U_f}$ is the 'upper average' of $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f}$ on $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{[0,1]}$ with respect to partition $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{P}$.

If these lower and upper averages limits converge to the same value (id est: are equal), we are given "my definition of average" of $f$. If they do not converge, then the average is undefined. Notice I define "upper" and "lower" averages to show when an average can not exist.

Note I describe $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{L(f, P)}$ and $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{U(f, P)}$ as "Riemman-like" because original Riemman-sums have upper and lower sums. However, this doesn't mean they are the same. Here we discard empty sub-interval with no points. This means my average could be anywhere between $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(0)}$ and $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(1)}$ depending on $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{A}$, and possibly initial $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{P}$.

Comment: You probably wanted to link to this question: [How do prove the Darboux-like sum of a function, defined on a countable set with infinite limit points, converges to zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3637157) You link goes to a picture instead: "Since no one has answered [my question][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oD9M.png) on MSE..." (BTW the question on [math.se] still has a bounty.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Fixed it.

Comment: The generation procedure of the partition P is unclear to me. Suppose initially $A = \{ 1/6, 1/4, 3/4, 5/6\}$. And you start with $n = 3$. You end up with the first and third intervals having 2 points each, and the middle interval with no point. Do you or do you not modify the middle interval? Is $n'$ here supposed to be $2$ or $3$?

Comment: If your answer is $n' = 2$, then it contradicts what you have written as your procedure. If your answer is $n'  =3$, then your definition of the lower sum will involve taking the $\inf$ over an empty set.

Comment: @WillieWong You do not modify the middle interval so $n^{\prime}=3$.  So we take the $\text{inf}$ over an empty set which is "undefined". According to one of the lines in my post, if $t_i$ is undefined, then $P(t_i)$ should be zero. How do I make this more clear in my post?

Comment: You should probably define what $P(t_i)$ means then. (I had no idea what that sentence was supposed to mean, until your comment.)

Comment: Can you be more precise what you mean by refinement of $P$? If you start with $m$ being a multiple of $n$ (so that the initial grid before merging is a refinement), is it obvious that the generated grid is a refinement? Specifically, suppose I start with $A = \{0.0001, 1 - 0.0001\}$. With $n = 3$ there is two possible $P$s, either $\{[0,2/3], [2/3,1]\}$ or $\{[0,1/3], [1/3,1]\}$. With $n = 6$, however, there are 5 possible $P$s, each containing two elements, most of which are not refinements of either of the previous partition.

Comment: Actually, here's a better example of the problem with the refinement process: let $A = \{1/8,  3/8\}$. Starting from $n = 2$ the partition generated with have $n' = 2$, dividing the interval at $1/2$. Starting from $n = 4$ the partition generated will also have $n' = 2$, but now the intervals are divided at $1/4$. With $n = 6$ you also get $n' = 2$ with dividing point at $1/3$.

Comment: @WillieWong You're right, the refinement $P$ does not always approach $\infty$, especially for finite $A$. What should I say instead?

Comment: Is the fact that you are doing things "Darboux-like" important? What if you just formulate it using the "Riemann" version? I believe for a fixed $A$, for each $n$, the number $n'$ is well-defined. And so it makes sense to talk about $U_{f,n}$ and $L_{f,n}$. And it also makes sense to talk about their $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ as $n\to \infty$. The Darboux formulation of integrability using Darboux sums and refinements has the benefit that under refinement, the upper sum is monotonically decreasing, and the lower sum is monotonically increasing, and so their limits are well-defined.

Comment: If there were any sort of monotonicity properties in your problem that makes the refinement language useful, you should expect that $L_{f,P}$ to be monotonically increasing. For the test case you have, however, your $f$ is non-negative on the interval, and hence $L_{f,P} \geq 0$ always. If it were to monotonically increase, and if your conjecture holds that it increases to limit 0, then you must have that $L_{f,P} \equiv 0$ for any $P$, which is obviously false. So I would advise forgetting about this whole refinement business.

Comment: @WillieWong I want cases where the average of $P$ is undefined. That is the upper and lower sum does not converge. Consider $P(x)=x^2$ on a countably dense set and $P(x)=x$ on another countable dense set. Both countable dense sets are disjoint. I want the average to be undefined. A darboux-like sum would show this, not Riemann. (Sorry my response took so long, my laptop is typing two letters each time I hit a key. I have to constatly delete a letter. sseeee wwhhaaaatt II mmeeaann. :((

Comment: It still works with Riemann: you can have an upper limit and a lower limit that do not agree with each other. (Pretty much this is what people mean when a function is not Riemann integrable.)

Comment: @WillieWong Is it possible for you to edit my post. My tutor and I will keep making careless mistakes.

Comment: @WillieWong How are the new edits?

Comment: It is not clear to me why the lower and upper limits exist. At the heart of my confusion is this process of "merging intervals". This destroys the monotonicity of the refinement process.  Additionally, the "merging intervals" process is not well defined: if you have three intervals next to each other, with 1, 0, 1 point of A in the intervals respectively, do you merge the first two or the latter two?

Comment: @WillieWong The lower and upper sum exist, to define when an average can't be defined. In your example, when you "merge intervals", it could be the first two or the latter two. However, I prefer it's the first two.

Comment: For anyone who has more questions, speak in this [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107629/new-discovery-riemman-like-sum).

Comment: @LSpice Why is my question unclear. I already have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the concrete question you ask, the answer is yes.

Your set $A$ is in fact the set of all numbers between $0$ and $1$ with binary expansion that has no more than 3 bits equaling 1.

Let $\ell_+ = \lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ and $\ell_- = \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$. You can estimate

$$ n' \geq (\ell_- - 1) + \binom{\ell_- - 1}{2} + \binom{\ell_- - 1}{3} \approx \ell_-^3 $$

On the other hand, the sum inside either the upper/lower sum is between

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{\ell_+} 2^{-i} + \sum_{i = 1}^{\ell_+} \sum_{j = i+1}^{\ell_+} (2^{-i} + 2^{-j}) + \sum_{i = 1}^{\ell_+} \sum_{j = i+1}^{\ell_+}\sum_{k = j+1}^{\ell_+} (2^{-i} + 2^{-j} + 2^{-k}) $$

(which is the sum of all numbers in $A$ with no more than 3 bits equaling 1 *and* least significant bit at least $2^{-\ell_+}$) and

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{\ell_+} (2^{-i} + 2^{-\ell_-}) + \sum_{i = 1}^{\ell_+} \sum_{j = i+1}^{\ell_+} (2^{-i} + 2^{-j}+ 2^{-\ell_-}) + \sum_{i = 1}^{\ell_+} \sum_{j = i+1}^{\ell_+}\sum_{k = j+1}^{\ell_+} (2^{-i} + 2^{-j} + 2^{-k}+ 2^{-\ell_-}) $$

(which is the sum of the same set of numbers of the first sum, increased by the width of the interval).

The first sum is easily evaluated to be $O(\ell_+^2)$ (here we take advantage of the fact that at least one level of the summation converges using geometric series).  The second sum is $O(\ell_+^2) + O(\ell_+^3 2^{-\ell_-})$.

So this means that both the upper sum and the lower sum behave like $\frac{C}{\log_2(n)} \to 0$ as $n \to +\infty$.

(This explains why your numerical computation goes very slow. At $n = 10^{-170}$, $\log_2(n)$ is something like 800. In fact, I don't even know if there is a reasonable numerical method for this, since to get convergence to the 10th decimal place, you will need a floating point arithmetic with a 2^30 bit mantissa to avoid numerical errors, or alternatively invent a new way to do exact arithmetic with rational numbers with very large numerators and denominators.)

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a better way of defining my sums (in general, not the example)? Perhaps you can edit my post. If I present my version of the definition, no one will show interest. My guess is the "highest-order limit points" will determine the average.

Comment: Can't help you there, because I have no idea why you even care about this sum. The procedure of "merging" is very strange. It would make more sense (to me) to define $n'$ from a given partition $P$ as "number of intervals in $P$ with non-empty intersection with $A$"; this makes the number a lot easier to count. Your definition on the other hand can take values between this one and twice that, and is a lot harder to count.

Comment: I can only answer this question because the expected sum is 0. If you look at $f(x) = 1 + x$, I don't know how even to prove either the upper or the lower sum has converging limits.

Comment: In my post, I state about first-order, second-order,...$n$-th order limit points. I want the $n$th order limit point to have "infinitely more weight" in the average then $n-1$th, $n-2$th...$1$st order limit points and finite points. I want the $n-1$-th order limit point to have "inifnitely more weight" then the $n-2$th, $n-3$th...first order limit points and finite points. The only way to do this is to create something similar to my definition. At the same time if we have multiple limit points of the highest order, the one where the lower-order limit points converges........

Comment: .........the slowest should have more weight depending on the rate of convergence compared to rate of convergence to the other highest order limit points.

Comment: As for your example, I expect the sums should converge to $1$, considering $A$ stays the same.

Comment: Why should it converge to 1? There may be a lot of empty intervals, where you require that the $\inf$ evaluates to 0. Up to half of the intervals can be empty in the worst case scenario. (Which is why in [my comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359027/prove-or-disprove-this-riemann-like-sum-of-a-function-defined-on-a-countable-se/359105?noredirect=1#comment903701_359105) I talked about looking at $n'$ being the number of intervals with non-zero intersection with $A$. In this case then the average of a constant function is the constant, and not something else.)

Comment: The merged sub-interval must be as long as possible without having more than one element in $A$. This means we can keep merging empty sub-intervals until the merged sub-interval until adding another sub-interval will make the merged sub-interval have more than one element in $A$, so we avoid adding it. In this case, the merged sub-intervals will always have one element.

Comment: Now consider $f(x)=x+1$ and $A=(0,1/3)\cup (2/3,1)$. As $s\to 0$, around $1/3$ of the sub-intervals, all existing in $[1/3,2/3]$, will be empty. We merge these sub-intervals. If we add another sub-interval it will have infinite more elements in $A$, which is greater than $1$. So we avoid adding another one.

Comment: There are fractal like constructions that allows very frequently half of the intervals to be empty, and not in a way you can merge. Let $B$ denote all infinite subsets of the square numbers {1, 4, 9, ...}. Let $A: \{ \exists b \in B: x = \sum_{i\in b} 2^{-i} \}$. Then for any $s = 2^{-k^2 - 1}$, the corresponding $P$ has exactly half of its intervals containing infinitely many points, and half of its intervals exactly empty.

Comment: Incidentally, for this last example, every point in $A$ is an "infinite-order" limit point. If you define $n'$ to only range over all non-empty intervals, then the "average" process you define should be able to be expressed in terms of integrating $f$ against some singular continuous measure supported on the closure of $A$.

Comment: Here is [another attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3725235/125918). I am one step closer. :)